# CSS Property doesn't apply when screen width changed. Using both css and jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

HTML:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<div class="one">Hello World</div>
```

CSS:

```
p, div.one {
  color: black;
}
```

Javascript:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    console.log('resize called');
    var width = $(window).width();
    if (width >= 400 && width <= 500) {
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $("p").css("color", "red");
        $("div.one").css("color", "green");
      });
    }
  })
  .resize();
```

JSFiddle Link: https://jsfiddle.net/misteeque/q5t5j7q3/4/

Basically I want the text color changed to red and green when screen size is between 400 and 500, which happens without any problem, but when the screen size is changed back out of the range, i.e. either more than 500 or less than 400, the color remains red and green, and it is not changed back to black, as I've defined in CSS.

What is going wrong in here? Thanks.

Note that using both CSS and jQuery is mandatory here.

Comment: because you're applying a style to the element when it enters that width, there's nothing to remove the style when the width goes out of that range, so therefore the style is never "un"-applied

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inline element styles have higher specificity than any css applied styles, so you can solve the issue by clearing `style` attribute of the elements in `else` clause of your if statement like this...

```
if (width >= 400 && width <= 500) {
  $("p").css("color", "red");
  $("div.one").css("color", "green");
} else {
  $("p,div.one").attr("style", "");
}
```

JSFiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/q5t5j7q3/8/

Answer (score 1):

The styles that you've added through Javascript dont' get removed once the screen goes out of that 400-500 range.

You could add a check to make sure they reset, but this is much, much easier with CSS media queries:

```css
@media (min-width: 400px) and (max-width:500px) {
  p { color: red }
  div.one { color: green }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/q5t5j7q3/7/

Comment: It's best to use CSS whenever you can... Nice answer @murraybunton, upvoted :-) However, If you have to use JS ( due to design decision made earlier ) check out my answer... ;-)

Comment: thanks for the answer @murraybunton, but as I mentioned before, I have to use jQuery, because I am going to apply this solution in a jQuery code I have written, and I cannot use CSS there.

Answer (score 1):

You can add else and remove the css you have added (watch it in "full page" and change the screen size)

```js
$(window).resize(function() {
    console.log('resize called');
    var width = $(window).width();
    if (width >= 400 && width <= 500) {
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $("p").css("color", "red");
        $("div.one").css("color", "green");
      });
    }
    else
    {
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $("p").css("color", "");
        $("div.one").css("color", "");
      });
    }
  })
  .resize();
```

```css
p, div.one {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<div class="one">Hello World</div>
```